# How to get the last part of a string?

Tags: c#, regex

Given this string:

```
http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType
```

I want to get the last part of it: "BusinessRelationType"

I have been thinking about reversing the whole string then looking for the first "/", take everything to the left of that and reverse that. However, I'm hoping there is a better/more concise method. Thoughts?

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 130, accepted):

one-liner with Linq:

```
var lastPart = text.Split('/').Last();
```

or if you might have empty strings in there (plus null option):

```
var lastPart = text.Split('/').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: This solution is good, but if the link have this structure: `http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType/` note the final slash, the content of `lastPart` will be empty. Using this:
`string lastPart = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf('/')).Split('/').Last();` will fix the problem :)

Comment: I tried using this but got errors, seems that I'm not familiar with using Linq methods.  Any chance a line could be added explaining that part?

Comment: There is a better answer than mine on here by @benp44: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387775/14777

Answer (score 101):

Whenever I find myself writing code such as `LastIndexOf("/")`, I get the feeling that I am probably doing something that's unsafe, and there is likely a better method already available.

As you are working with a URI, I would recommend using the `System.Uri` class. This provides you with validation and safe, easy access to any part of the URI.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType");
string lastSegment = uri.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer the other ones are dirty solutions imo

Comment: This answer is the best one. Not sure why the 'hacky' ones are in the top.

Comment: This is great, and so convenient for grabbing the Id from the location header of a creation.

Answer (score 40):

You can use [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx).

```
int position = s.LastIndexOf('/');
if (position > -1)
    s = s.Substring(position + 1);
```

Another option is to use a `Uri`, if that's what you need. This has a benefit of parsing other parts of the uri, and dealing well with the query string, eg: `BusinessRelationType?q=hello world`

```
Uri uri = new Uri(s);
string leaf = uri.Segments.Last();
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`string.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) to find the last / and then [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904307.aspx) to get everything after it:

```
int index = text.LastIndexOf('/');
string rhs = text.Substring(index + 1);
```

Note that as `LastIndexOf` returns -1 if the value isn't found, this the second line will return the whole string if there is no / in the text.

Comment: I'm curious what is the performance of this approach: `var suffix = new string(str.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => c != '.').ToArray());`. Since `Reverse` is a "lazy" method that returns `Enumerable`, I think it should be good, no?

Comment: @gdoron: That ends up allocating rather a lot of objects unnecessarily, I'd say. It also gives a reversed result, which I don't think was asked for

Answer (score 10):

Here is a pretty concise way to do this:

```
str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    return url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

A small tip for any silly or unobservant people (or anyone who has recently given up coffee and is silly, unobservant, grouchy...like myself) - Windows file paths use a `'\'`...all of the examples here on the other hand, use a `'/'`.

So use a `'\\'` to get the end of a Windows file path! :)

The solutions here are perfect and complete, but perhaps this might prevent some other poor soul from wasting an hour as I just did!

Comment: Using @"\path\to\something" is a cleaner way in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer might give undesidered results (empty string) if the url ends with /

To prevent this you can use:

```
string lastPart = text.TrimEnd('/').Split('/').Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use regular expression `/([^/]*?)$` to find match

Comment: Laziness doesn't work barwards, but you don't need it here anyway. `[^/]*$` will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
Path.GetFileName
```

considers / and \ as separators.

```
Path.GetFileName ("http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType") =
"BusinessRelationType"
```

Answer (score 0):

**For String:**

```
var stringUrl = "http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType";
var lastPartOfUrl = stringUrl.Substring(stringUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

**If you convert string to Uri:** // Totally depends on your requirement.

```
var stringUrl = "http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType";
var convertStringToUri = new Uri(stringUrl);
var lastPartOfUrl = convertStringToUri.PathAndQuery.Substring(convertStringToUri.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Output:

```
BusinessRelationType
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could attempt to also do:

```
string x = "http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/BusinessRelationType"
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)?x.Split('/').Last(): x,
```

Comment: Please add code formatting by making sure code is indented exactly 4 spaces for the leftmost lines or marking after pasting and hitting ctrl+k, You will often have to then correct first line by manually indenting and sometimes even repeat the process, but as it stands it violates guidelines by dumping code in text